# Is there a way to use devenv.exe on the command line to link-only a project instead of full-build a project?

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, msbuild, linker

Is there a way to use devenv.exe on the command line to link-only a project instead of full-build a project?

`devenv.exe /?` provides the below commands, none of which appear able to link-only a project instead of full-build a project.

> /Build /Clean /Command /Deploy /Edit /LCID /Log /NoVSIP /Out /Project
>   /ProjectConfig /Rebuild /ResetAddin /ResetSettings /ResetSkipPkgs /Run
>   /RunExit /SafeMode /Upgrade

I am interested in this because the `/LTCG:PGOPTIMIZE` phase of profile-guided optimization entails a relink without a recompile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that vcbuild.exe can be used to perform a link-only using its /forcelink option:

```
vcbuild.exe PgoProject.vcproj "ReleasePGOptimize|x64" /forcelink
```

link.exe would also work, though with increased difficulty in getting the arguments right, because link.exe does not accept a .vcproj file containing the linker flags whereas vcbuild.exe does.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply invoke `link.exe` (the linker) with the appropriate [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx). There's no need to involve `devenv.exe`.

Comment: You'll have to remove "simple".